# Recursive triggers - one trigger releasing another (update statements)

Tags: triggers, sql-update, firebird

I created 5 triggers in my small (2 table database).

After I added the last one (to change INVPOS.INVSYMBOL after INVOICE.SYMBOL has been updated) these triggers activated each other and I got a

```
 Too many concurrent executions of the same request.
```

error.

Could you please look at the triggers I created and help me out?

What can I do to avoid these problems in future? Should I merge a few triggers into one?

Comment: You will probably get a better response if you include the relevant details in your question.

Comment: I use triggers to achieve a few desired functions: prevent from inserting 0 to AMOUNT and PRICENET, calculate NETVAL, copy INVPOS.INVSYMBOL from INVOICE.SYMBOL, calculate SUMNETVAL, automatically change INVPOS.INVSYMBOL when INVOICE.SYMBOL is updated.

Comment: I used a few triggers (before/after on UPDATE and sometimes on INSERT). Some triggers perform UPDATE queries to copy data or calculate some values so they activate the other triggers and these activate the first ones. I have no idea how to fix it. I thought about merging a few triggers into a bigger one but I dont think it will solve the problem.

Comment: What extra information would be necessary to answer this question?

Comment: What I meant was include the relevant details (as in DDL) in your question, not link to a database file. If the DDL is large, then you could also link to a DDL script so people don't have to go through the effort of downloading and opening the database.For example by the sound of it, `INVSYMBOL` is either a foreign key (in which case it can be automatically updated) or it is denormalized data (in which case you should just be able to remove it).

Comment: Thanks, posting DDL is a good idea. But what about trigger definitions? I think posting them would take a lot of space.

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to check has the intresting field(s) changed and only run the trigger's action if really nessesary (data has changed), ie

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Foo FOR T
AS
BEGIN
  -- only execute update statement when the Fld changed
  if(new.Fld is distinct from old.Fld)then begin
     update ...
  end
END
```

Another option could be to check has the trigger already done it's thing in this transaction, ie

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Foo FOR T
AS
DECLARE trgrDone VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  trgrDone = RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'Foo');
  IF(trgrDone IS NULL)THEN BEGIN
     -- trigger hasn't been executed yet
     -- register the execution
     rdb$set_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'Foo', 1);
     -- do the work which might cause reentry
     update ...
  END
END
```

Comment: I need to add one more functionality to my database. If the INVOICE.STATUS is changed to a positive number, then it means the invoice has been accepted. Once it is accepted, there can be no changes to some columns of the linked INVPOS (invoice positions). I thought about adding a "if(invoice.status <0) then begin" check to every trigger that updates certain data but I dont think it is a good solution. Can you think of something better?

Comment: You could use just one `before update` trigger where you do the "no changes allowed" check and raise exception when the invoice is accepted and cant change anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid circular references between triggers.

In general, triggers are not suitable for complex business logic, they work good for simple "if-then" business rules.

For the case you described you'd better implemenent a stored procedure where you could prepare data for all tables (perform data check, calculate necessary values, etc) and then insert them. It will lead to straightforward, fast and easy-to-maintain code.

Also, use `CHECK` for "preventing from inserting 0 to `AMOUNT` and `PRICENET`", and calculated fields for tasks like "calculate `NETVAL`".